# how do I import replit module to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replit

I made a blackjack game and a calculator following an online tutorial, however the only tutorial used replit module (from replit import clear -> clear() ) (replit being the website/online interpreter). I am now trying the same program in vscode:

1. is there a way to import replit to vscode?
2. is there a similar module to get the same result?
   I have seen some people make suggestions to clear console but they all seem to depend on which OS I am running, since my desktop is windows and laptop is mac I want something that can work on both.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make the replit package work either, but you can use this instead:

```
   import os
   def clear():
       os.system('clear')
```

Then call the clear() function wherever you need in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try "import os" at the beginning of code and using "os.system('clear')"?
This should work on any OS or code editor/IDE.

Comment: "This should work on any OS" no, no it shouldn't.